# Identifying subset of variables with most predictive power of the other variables

Tags: modeling

I have 31 numeric variables (e.g., A-AF) for which I am attempting to identify the smallest subset of those variables that will predict the values of the remainder of the variables with a CI of 90% or greater.

For example, I would like end up with a model in which the values of variables A, B, C, D, and E, together, predict the values of F-AF, where variables A-E are the minimum number of variables needed to predict every other variable in the data.

How might I approach this problem?

I have the idea to create 31 different models to predict all 31 variables with 90% CI, then use some kind of "common variable" algorithm to identify which variables are common to all the models... But I don't know how to implement that.

I'm using RapidMiner 6, but I could learn to use R or any other tool to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there aren't any good answers to your question that have any formal guarantees to them. What you're asking is a special case of a general problem of searching in lattices. The key observation here is that if a subset of variables is not good at predicting the rest, then a subset of these will cannot be any better. Thus a strategy that's as good as any is along the lines of what you suggest: start with all but one of the variables and predict the remaining one. Then take the one with the best CI and explore outwards by dropping one variable at a time, and so on. This method comes up in many different forms when searching through subsets of a feature set.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Suresh. Could you name some of the methods that are used to do this kind of subset search? That will help me get started in the right direction.

Comment: The "inverse" of this is a method known as association rule mining where you grow upwards from the empty set. But conceptually it's the same thing. that might be one place to start.

Comment: Great. What do you think about ordination? Maybe something like  principal components analysis? I've never used it before, but it sounds like it might be applicable.